Can't listen to scroll from background in Bottom Sheet
I'm using showModalBottomSheet with DraggableScrollableSheet, I need to listen to scrolling of the bottom sheet (when scrolling to close the bottom sheet), it's working fine when the scroll is from the body (DraggableScrollableSheet / SingleChildScrollView widget) but when the scroll is from the background (BackdropFilter widget) it doesn't work, here's an example of the problem:
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final DraggableScrollableController draggableScrollableController = DraggableScrollableController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _showBs(context),
        tooltip: 'Show bs',
        child: const Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget backgroundWidget() {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
      child: Container(
        height: double.maxFinite,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBs(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      builder: (context) {
        return NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (notification) {
            print('Working only when scroll from body');
            return true;
          },
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              backgroundWidget(),
              draggableWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget draggableWidget() {
    return DraggableScrollableSheet(
      expand: false,
      maxChildSize: 0.5,
      minChildSize: 0.0,
      initialChildSize: 0.5,
      controller: draggableScrollableController,
      builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: scrollController,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            height: 500,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


I tried a lot of different ways to find a solution but nothing

Are you trying to close the showModalBottomSheet using the background? or do you want to listen to the scroll values of the draggable widget from the background widget?

LISTEN. You can copy paste the code in your side and see.. it's possible to scroll from the background, but then the scroll listener not trigger
